# If the Grothendieck ring of a semiring on a free commutative monoid is unital, is the original semiring unital?

Tags: ring-theory, semiring

Suppose $S$ is an associative semiring whose underling commutative monoid is free (in particular, cancellative) and that its Grothendieck ring $G(S)$ is a unital ring. Can we conclude that $S$ must be unital, and if not, is there a nice counter-example?

Alternatively, are there additional suppositions we can put on $S$ which would allow us to conclude the unitality of $S$ from that of $G(S)$?

The context is that I am struggling to disprove that a particular ring I have constructed is unital, but I have proven it is of the form $G(S)$ for $S$ which is not unital, and I am hoping this helps me somehow.

Comment: I answered this negatively on mathoverflow.

Comment: Roughly speaking if S is a semigroup but not a monoid the semiring $\mathbb NS$ never has a unit but the semigroup ring $\mathbb ZS$ can depending on S.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393142/if-the-grothendieck-ring-of-a-semiring-on-a-free-commutative-monoid-is-unital-i/393148#393148